# combine 2 columns of dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a data frame

```
data = [['Nan', 10], [4, 'Nan'], ['Nan', 12], ['Nan', 13], [5, 'Nan'], [6, 'Nan'], [7, 'Nan'], ['Nan', 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['min', 'max'])
print(df)
```

my dataset looks like,

```
min    max
Nan    10
4      Max
Nan    12
Nan    13
5      Nan 
6      Nan
7      Nan
Nan    8
```

I want to create a new column which will take one value from min then one value from max. If there are cont. 2 values of min/max (as we can see that 12 and 13 are 2 values) I have to consider only one value (consider only 12 and then move to select min)

In short,
new column should have one min value row, then one max value row and so on.

OUTPUT should be

```
combined
10
4
12
5
8
```

Comment: Can there be two non-nan values on the same row?

Comment: no it wont be possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change those values of `min` and `max` with  previous row not `NaN` to `NaN` using [`.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html).  Then remove the rows with both `min` and `max` being `NaN`.   Then update those `NaN` value in `min` with the value of `max` in each row using [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)

df['min'] = df['min'].where(df['min'].shift().isna())
df['max'] = df['max'].where(df['max'].shift().isna())
df = df.dropna(how='all')
df['combined'] = df['min'].combine_first(df['max'])
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   min   max  combined
0  NaN  10.0      10.0
1  4.0   NaN       4.0
2  NaN  12.0      12.0
4  5.0   NaN       5.0
7  NaN   8.0       8.0
```

Comment: its not printing the output as you have shown please check

Comment: This is the output after running your code. 0  Nan  10      Nan

Comment: @sam  You mean just one row ?  That's weird.

Comment: yes. can you post a complete code to try at my end?

Comment: @maybe your `NaN` are just text rather than np.nan.

Comment: I have checked with actual Nan as well as "Nan" too.

Comment: @sam   Just add the line `df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)` as the first step.
`

Comment: @sam  Try again.  I tested it ok after adding the line to replace text 'Nan' to np.nan

Comment: @Sam Let's me know if any further thing I can help!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stack the dataframe to reshape into a multiindex series then reset the level 1 index, then using boolean indexing filter/select only rows where the `min` is followed by `max` or vice-a-versa

```
s = df[df != 'Nan'].stack().reset_index(name='combined', level=1)
m = s['level_1'] != s['level_1'].shift()
s[m].drop('level_1', 1)
```

---

```
   combined
0      10.0
1       4.0
2      12.0
4       5.0
7       8.0
```

Comment: its not printing as output required.

Comment: I think the `Nan` values are string in your dataframe, let us first mask the `Nan` values with actual `NaN` then try the solution.

Comment: have checked with actual Nan too, but its not printing output as expected

Comment: now it prints all rows, can you post complete code which you tried because its not woring

Comment: the solution is working fine on the sample dataframe, right?

Comment: no its not working with sample dataset too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232727/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define the first key for the first value that you want to include, for example, 'max' and then iterate through the DataFrame, and append the values to your data structure while changing the key. At the same time, you will have to check for 'NaN' values since you have a lot of those,

```
combined = []
key = 'max'
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if not row[key] != row[key]:
    combined.append(row[key])
    if key == 'max':
      key = 'min'
    else:
      key = 'max'
```

Here, I have just hardcoded in the first value, but if you do not want to do that you can just check which column in the first row has an actual value that is not 'NaN' and then make that the key.

Note: I have added the data to a list, because I am not sure how you plan to include this as a column when the lengths will be different.

Comment: Let me know if you want the logic for how to check which key should be used first.

Answer (score 0):

If my assumptions are correct then this should work.

1. The value is 'Nan' string and not np.NaN
2. If the min column has 'Nan' value then max column will have number and vice versa, it means no row can have two numbers.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = [['Nan', 10], [4, 'Nan'], ['Nan', 12], ['Nan', 13], [5, 'Nan'], [6, 'Nan'], [7, 'Nan'], ['Nan', 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['min', 'max'])


df['combined'] = np.where(df['min']!='Nan', df['min'], df['max'])
```

This is the output I get

```
   min  max combined
0  Nan   10       10
1    4  Nan        4
2  Nan   12       12
3  Nan   13       13
4    5  Nan        5
5    6  Nan        6
6    7  Nan        7
7  Nan    8        8
```

Comment: @SAKL output required is different, please check output posted in the question